# Assign comma class to multiple columns in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` with several numeric columns to which i'd
like assign "comma" class.
This is needed becuase i have a central data frame which i filter and save to excel using Openxlsx package.
and the comma class is needed so that the data is shown as comma format in excel

here is the dataframe:

```
set.seed(10)
df_central_database <- data.frame(Category = as.character(sample(words[1:10], size = 50, replace = TRUE)) ,
           Summ_Income =sample(1000:10000, size = 50, replace = TRUE),
           Summ_Securities =sample(1000:10000, size = 50, replace = TRUE),
           Summ_Bonds =sample(1000:10000, size = 50, replace = TRUE),
           Summ_Options =sample(1000:10000, size = 50, replace = TRUE)
           )

str(df_central_database)

'data.frame':   50 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Category       : Factor w/ 10 levels "a","able","about",..: 6 4 5 7 1 3 3 3 7 5 ...
 $ Summ_Income    : int  4189 9428 3213 5258 2724 6249 5135 5207 4598 5548 ...
 $ Summ_Securities: int  4099 1551 4321 4668 9229 8999 9854 5295 7242 4832 ...
 $ Summ_Bonds     : int  8916 2774 1625 2416 4001 2620 2318 3615 9425 1922 ...
 $ Summ_Options   : int  3008 5823 6963 8633 2342 7031 7855 9988 3369 8967 ...
```

now changing the columns class is done with one line for each column like this:

```
class(df_central_database$Summ_Income) <- "comma"
class(df_central_database$Summ_Securities) <- "comma"
class(df_central_database$Summ_Bonds) <- "comma"
class(df_central_database$Summ_Options) <- "comma"


str(df_central_database)

'data.frame':   50 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Category       : Factor w/ 10 levels "a","able","about",..: 6 4 5 7 1 3 3 3 7 5 ...
 $ Summ_Income    :Class 'comma'  int [1:50] 4189 9428 3213 5258 2724 6249 5135 5207 4598 5548 ...
 $ Summ_Securities:Class 'comma'  int [1:50] 4099 1551 4321 4668 9229 8999 9854 5295 7242 4832 ...
 $ Summ_Bonds     :Class 'comma'  int [1:50] 8916 2774 1625 2416 4001 2620 2318 3615 9425 1922 ...
 $ Summ_Options   :Class 'comma'  int [1:50] 3008 5823 6963 8633 2342 7031 7855 9988 3369 8967 ...
```

Is it possible to do the class assignments using dplyr mutate_at
like something like this?

```
df_central_database %>%
  mutate_at(.vars = vars(contains("Summ")), 
            .funs = class(df_central_database$Income) <- "comma") %>%
  str()
```

or any other shortcut that will help me change several columns class to comma with a single swoop.

Thanks
Rafael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to use `dplyr`, then you can create a custom function to do the conversion and apply it via `mutate_at`, i.e.

```
f1 <- function(x){
    class(x) <- 'comma'
    return(x)
}

df_central_database %>% 
 mutate_at(vars(contains('Summ')), funs(f1)) %>% 
 str()
```

Which gives the structure,

> ```
> 'data.frame': 50 obs. of  5 variables:
>  $ Category       : Factor w/ 10 levels "a","able","about",..: 5 8 6 3 8 8 8 2 3 4 ...
>  $ Summ_Income    :Class 'comma'  int [1:50] 4397 3204 1788 4520 2643 2202 3317 5979 2332 9667 ...
>  $ Summ_Securities:Class 'comma'  int [1:50] 2263 9182 9100 2731 5791 5699 2443 5676 3020 3533 ...
>  $ Summ_Bonds     :Class 'comma'  int [1:50] 2544 5690 7882 3599 4931 7025 1332 6046 9392 4912 ...
>  $ Summ_Options   :Class 'comma'  int [1:50] 7237 1865 1332 4608 1103 6111 9505 4090 3200 5875 ...
> ```

Comment: This is literally one hundred times slower than the base R version in my answer.

Comment: @Spacedman I don't doubt it. I never said It has any advantages. I was merely accommodating OP's request for a `dplyr` based solution.

Comment: it also said "or any other shortcut". Many dplyr users have never typed `for(`. *sigh*

Comment: @Spacedman yes. So you provided the shortcut, I provided the `dplyr`. I don't get why you attack me. I don't know ( neither do I care) why people do what they do or write code the way they write code. As for myself... I never used `for(` because I do everything with `apply` , or `Reduce(..., accumulate = TRUE)` to grasp previous loop results... + `tidyverse` and `data.table` (just getting the hang of it now)

Comment: The OP now has more information about the solutions. Slow and dplyr, or fast+base. Its not an "attack" on you or the answer. Normally I'd not mention the typical x2 or x3 slowdown with dplyr, but 100x needed pointing out.

Comment: @Spacedman I agree. I misinterpreted your intentions. Apologies for that... Mondays tend to make people more frustrated than reality :). Anyway, good pointing it out... I 'd go (along with all other R-users) with fast and base

Answer (score 5):

Get the names of the things you want to change into a vector:

```
> changers = names(df_central_database)[grepl("Summ",names(df_central_database))]
> changers
[1] "Summ_Income"     "Summ_Securities" "Summ_Bonds"      "Summ_Options"
```

And then bang them into a loop:

```
> for(n in changers){class(df_central_database[[n]])= "comma"}
```

No need for extra packages to do this.

Comment: Were you including the `str()` in timings of this? Because I am getting the loop and dplyr at nearly identical timings, and a `lapply` using `\`class<-\`` as being an order of magnitude faster than both of these.